# Rails active record query using MySQL UDF

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using MySQL user-defined functions in my Rails app (levenshtein ratio related) for selecting similar strings. For example, i am selecting similar models ordering by "similarity" like that:

```
@something = Something.select("*", "levenshtein_ratio(name, '#{Mysql2::Client.escape(name)}') as l_ratio").having("l_ratio > ?", minratio).order("l_ratio DESC")
```

It works fine, there are two questions though:

1. Is there a better, more "native" way to do the same thing?
2. How can i get l_ratio value from the selected objects? ActiveRecord object won't contain it.